# Drupal high number of queries

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have Drupal site and it is very slow. It's on localhost and it takes 4-5 sec to load one page. 
I enabled general_log in mysql and i saw that for just one page drupal executes more than 2000 queries...

Is there way to speed up this ?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal can be a beast if not optimized for production:
General guideline:

- Disabled devel module
- Disabled Views UI
- Enabled any Views caching (views content cache)
- Enable Page caching
- Enable Block caching
- Disable database logging (use syslog instead)
- Disable the statistics module

Note: If your site makes use of authenticated traffic (logged in users to Drupal), this is a completely different paradigm in which most of the caching efforts above are ignored for logged in users.

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve that is to turn on all the different forms of caching. You may not see much of a difference when you are logged in, but guests can often see a substantial speedup. Also consolidating JS and CSS files helps a lot.

If you use the devel module, you can see all the queries and the time they take. It's very convenient.